# Constant ping batch file with .csv output not working correctly

Tags: batch-file

I am having Internet problems and wanted to create a background script that sets a constant ping to my router and the Internet so that I can track how often the connection drops.

What I have managed to do is create a batch file which does a constant ping to my router & the Internet, gets the response time and then creates an output in the console as well as a CSV file with multiple fields such as status (i.e. Successful ping or failure) ping time, ping date e.t.c.

The problem I have is the code I have does not output if the connection drops and I think this is because the `%errorlevel%` variable I have put does not work due to the ping output is chopped up and stored in a variable, but I could be wrong and this is why I'm here explaining my issue.

I have tried multiple different methods but cannot find one where I can store the response time in a variable AND have it provide the correct error level to go to output the correct data all from the same ping

Seems right now I can get it to only do either one:

```
@ECHO OFF
@SETLOCAL

set internetAddress=8.8.8.8
set routerAddress=192.168.1.0
set speed=2
set filename=C:\PingTest\PingResults\PingTest_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.csv

echo Type, Status, Time, Date, ms >> %filename%
echo off

:internetstart

set currentTime=%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%
set currentDate=%date:~-10,2%/%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-4,4%

for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%G in ('
ping -4 -n 1 %internetAddress%^|findstr /i "TTL="') do (

set ims=%%G 
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto :internetSuccess
if not %errorlevel% == 0 goto :internetFail
)

:internetSuccess

echo internet = success @ %ims% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
echo internet, success, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %ims% >> %filename%
PING localhost -n %speed% >NUL
goto :routerstart

:internetFail
set ims=n/a
echo internet = failure @ %ims% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
echo internet, failure, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %ims% >> %filename%
PING localhost -n %speed% >NUL
goto :routerstart

:routerstart

for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%A in ('
ping -4 -n 1 %routerAddress%^|findstr /i "TTL="') do (

set rms=%%A 
if %errorlevel% == 0 goto :routerSuccess
if not %errorlevel% == 0 goto :routerFail
)

:routerSuccess
echo router   = success @ %rms% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
echo router, success, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %rms% >> %filename%
PING localhost -n %speed% >NUL
goto :internetstart

:routerFail
set rms=n/a
echo router   = failure @ %rms% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
echo router, failure, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %rms% >> %filename%
PING localhost -n %speed% >NUL
goto :internetstart
```

Expected results in the CSV file is:

If `ping` is successful:

```
|TYPE     | STATUS  |TIME      | DATE       | MS |
|internet | success | 00:00:00 | 31/12/9999 | 7ms|
|router   | success | 00:00:00 | 31/12/9999 | 1ms|
```

If `ping` fails:

```
|TYPE     | STATUS  |TIME      | DATE       | MS |
|internet | failure | 00:00:00 | 31/12/9999 | n/a|
|router   | failure | 00:00:00 | 31/12/9999 | n/a|
```

Current results:

If `ping` is successful:

```
|TYPE     | STATUS  |TIME      | DATE       | MS |
|internet | success | 00:00:00 | 31/12/9999 | 7ms|
|router   | success | 00:00:00 | 31/12/9999 | 1ms|
```

If `ping` fails:

```
|TYPE     | STATUS  |TIME      | DATE       | MS |
|internet | success | 00:00:00 | 31/12/9999 | 7ms|
|router   | success | 00:00:00 | 31/12/9999 | 7ms|
```

Comment: is there a reason to include the `powershell` tag when you are running BAT/CMD stuff?

Comment: apologies, was working on some powershell at the time so added it without thinking, removed now

Comment: Lots of free utilities that will do a much better job then your batch file will do.

Comment: Are you trying the `ErrorLevel` of `findstr` in the `for /F` loops? Well, this can't work, because the `ping`/`findstr` command line is executed in a separate `cmd` instance by `for /F`, but the `ErrorLevel` is the value from the current instance where your batch file runs in; in addition, you'd need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) for reading `ErrorLevel` in a loop where it is also set or changed in...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest the following code for the task:

```
@echo off

set "internetAddress=8.8.8.8"
set "routerAddress=192.168.1.1"
set "speed=2"
set "filename=C:\PingTest\PingResults\PingTest_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.csv"

(echo Type, Status, Time, Date, ms)>>%filename%

:internetstart
set "currentTime=%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%"
set "currentDate=%date:~-10,2%/%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-4,4%"

(ping -4 -n 1 %internetAddress% | findstr /i "TTL=")>nul 2>&1

if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    goto :internetfail
) else (
    for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%A in ('ping -4 -n 1 %internetAddress% ^| findstr /i "TTL="') do (
        set "ims=%%A"
    )
    goto :internetSuccess
)

:internetSuccess
echo internet = success @ %ims% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
(echo internet, success, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %ims%)>>%filename%
(ping localhost -n %speed%)>nul 2>&1
goto :routerstart

:internetFail
set "ims=n/a"
echo internet = failure @ %ims% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
(echo internet, failure, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %ims%)>>%filename%
(ping localhost -n %speed%)>nul 2>&1
goto :routerstart

:routerstart
(ping -4 -n 1 %routerAddress% | findstr /i "TTL=")>nul 2>&1

if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (
    goto :routerFail
) else (
    for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%B in ('ping -4 -n 1 %routerAddress% ^| findstr /i "TTL="') do (
        set "rms=%%B"
    )
    goto :routerSuccess
)

:routerSuccess
echo router   = success @ %rms% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
(echo router, success, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %rms%)>>%filename%
(ping localhost -n %speed%)>nul 2>&1
goto :internetstart

:routerFail
set "rms=n/a"
echo router   = failure @ %rms% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
(echo router, failure, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %rms%)>>%filename%
(ping localhost -n %speed%)>nul 2>&1
goto :internetstart
```

Your main problem here, is that your `%errorlevel%` variable handling was incorrect. When you are looping through a command, if there is no output **the whole `for` loop will be *skipped***. So, when the command failed, the `for` loop was skipped (nothing to loop; empty lines ignored).

Some other technical details were fixed; just to avoid unexpected behaviours.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the `delayedexpansion` while using a changing variable in a loop :

At start of your script :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Then :

```
:routerstart

for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%A in ('
ping -4 -n 1 %routerAddress%^|findstr /i "TTL="') do (

set rms=%%A 
if !errorlevel! == 0 ( 
         goto:routerSuccess
) else (
         goto:routerFail )
)
```

Comment: thanks, but this hasnt seemed to have worked, not it doesnt complete the output and closes cmd after one ping

Answer (score 1):

Be careful with `%errorlevel%` here as `destination host unreachable` will return `errorlevel 0`. Instead lets use `if defined` simply because `findstr` will only set `ims` and `rms` if it finds `TTL=`. We also do not need all of the labels, we can just do code block `if defined` statements with and the first for loop will fall through to the next, besides the last `goto start` the others can go, finally also no `delayedexpansion` needed:

```
@echo off
set "internetAddress=8.8.8.8"
set "routerAddress=192.168.1.1"
set speed=2
set filename=C:\PingTest\PingResults\PingTest_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%_%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%%date:~-4,4%.csv
echo %filename%
echo Type, Status, Time, Date, ms>>%filename%

:start
set ims=
set rms=
set "currentTime=%time:~0,2%:%time:~3,2%:%time:~6,2%"
set "currentDate=%date:~-10,2%/%date:~-7,2%/%date:~-4,4%"

for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%G in ('ping -4 -n 1 %internetAddress% ^| findstr /i "TTL="') do set "ims=%%G"
if defined ims ( 
    echo internet = success @ %ims% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
    echo internet, success, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %ims%>>%filename%
    timeout 2 /nobreak>nul
 ) else (
    echo internet = failure @ N/A - %currentTime% %currentDate%
    echo internet, failure, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, N/A>>%filename%
    timeout 2 /nobreak>nul
)

for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%A in ('ping -4 -n 1 %routerAddress%^|findstr /i "TTL="') do set "rms=%%A"
if defined rms (
    echo router = success @ %rms% - %currentTime% %currentDate%
    echo router, success, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, %rms%>>%filename%
    timeout 2 /nobreak>nul
 ) else (
    echo router   = failure @ N/A - %currentTime% %currentDate%
    echo router, failure, %currentTime%, %currentDate%, N/A>>%filename%
    timeout 2 /nobreak>nul
)
goto start
```